# any(Classmember) returns null mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to do when().thenReturn() but facing issues. Following is the sample code that I came up with for SOers:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Sample {
    public void function(List<SampleA> list) {
        for (SampleA s : list) {
            List<SampleB> nameList = s.v1;
            for (SampleB m : nameList) {
                SampleC value = m.getV2();
                if (value != null) {
                    doSomething(value);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.warn("No valid value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SampleA{
    List<SampleB> v1;
}

public class SampleB{
    SampleC v2;

    public SampleC getV2(){
        return this.v2;
    }
}
```

This might be silly but I just want to understand why can't I do:

```
SampleB sampleB = new SampleB();
when(sampleB.getV2()).thenReturn(any(SampleC.class));
```

Comment: You seem to be using a real rather than mocked instance within `when`. That won't work at all. You should be using `mock` to create a mocked instance of `SampleB`

Comment: @sprinter If I create the mock instance, then I need to mock all variables as well within that class. Why can't I simply pass different instances of the class based on the conditions?

Comment: That's not how mocking works. The idea is to test functionality of another class by passing in mocked instances of classes the class-under-test depends on. While there are mechanisms for partial mocking I recommend you don't use them (at least until you're very experienced in using mocking frameworks) because they have a lot of traps and are almost always a sign of bad design. Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to do we could explain how to achieve that with mocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to test `Sample.function` and are trying to work out how to mock `SampleC` values. If so, then your code should probably look something like:

```
@Test
void testFunction() {
    SampleC mockC = mock(SampleC.class);
    SampleB mockB = mock(SampleB.class);
    SampleA mockA = mock(SampleA.class);
    when(mockB.getV2()).thenReturn(mockC);
    when(mockA.getV1()).thenReturn(List.of(mockB));
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.function(List.of(mockA));
    // verify doSomething was called with mockC as its argument
    when(mockB.getV2()).thenReturn(null);
    sample.function(List.of(mockA));
    // verify "No valid value" was logged
}
```

I've added a `getV1` method rather than direct access to the field because my fingers refuse to write the code that directly accesses a public field :-)

If you're struggling with verifying that `doSomething` was called then that's where argument matching comes in. Ideally you'd have a `SomethingDoer` that you inject into your sample:

```
interface SomethingDoer {
    void doSomething(SampleC sample);
}

class Sample {
    private final SomethingDoer somethingDoer;

    public Sample(SomethingDoer somethingDoer) {
        this.somethingDoer = somethingDoer;
    }
}
```

Then you'd add the following to your test:

```
SomethingDoer doer = mock(SomethingDoer.class);
Sample sample = new Sample(doer);
...
verify(doer).doSomething(mockC);
```

Also note that the code above is poor style: the tests should be split up with the setup code in a `@BeforeEach` method. I've just put it in a single test to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score 0):

`any(…)` is an `ArgumentMatcher`. It is used to match arguments. You cannot use it to return instances of classes. What would "any SampleC" be?

You'd use it with mock objects, like so:

```java
SampleInterface sample = Mockito.mock(SampleInterface.class);
when(sample.function(any(List.class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
// or: .thenAnswer(a -> new ArrayList<>()); to return a new instance for each call
```

Comment: If I do `SampleB sampleB = new SampleB();
when(sampleB.getV2()).thenReturn(new SampleC());`

`
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
`

Comment: The above error is because I am using `new SampleB()` I have to do so, because in real codebase I have other parameters which are being mocked and being used.

Comment: If I do `SampleB.v2 = new SampleC()` then it works, but I am not sure if this is OK for testing purposes.

Comment: @amyJ you cannot – and should not – mock concrete classes. Use mocks to mock external interfaces. If you are in control of your classes OR the classes are simple data holders (with getters and setters), simply create a new instance and set the properties accordingly. Otherwise you will end up with an unmaintainable mess of `doReturn`/`doAnswer` calls which duplicate your real logic. Your tests become brittle and no longer test your real code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use ArgumentMatchers inside thenReturn or thenAnswer. You have to specify exactly what to return. For Example:

```
SampleB sampleB = mock(SampleB.class)
when(sampleB.getV2()).thenReturn(new SampleC());
```